# How to add Android Profiler to my Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I see in Android developers Guidelines that you can open it this way:

Click View > Tool Windows > Android Profiler (you can also click Android Profiler  in the toolbar).

But in my Tool Windows there is no Android profile option at all!
How can I add it to my Android Studio?

Comment: if you are running android studio 3.0 or above then u can find it alongside logcat in your tool windows. It will work with 5.0 and above

Comment: my android studio is 2.3.2 so I don't have it then?

Comment: yes you have to upgrade your android studio because it added in android studio 3.0

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Here is the solution Follow these [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68901695/11445727](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68901695/11445727)

Comment: You have to enable facets for specific project [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68901695/11445727](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68901695/11445727)

Answer (score 0):

The Profile option won't show up in tab until we build and run latest code of our branch. Just run again and Profile option would show up.

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51627124/1994950