# Android Profiler not appeared in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, profiler, memoryanalyzer

I want to analyze memory consumption in my device but I didn't find **Android profiler** tab in Android Studio as seen below :

[image]

Please who could help me to show up this tab.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you take a look at top menu you will see a **profile icon** click it and it will start your app with profile attached. See the below screenshot to get the idea.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**The perfect tip for Android Studio:**

When you need to find something, write it in the help tab, like this:

[image]

If you know what you're looking for, you will find it there :)

Answer (score 9):

I have faced this problem too. Here is the solution. You have to enable Android Facet for specific project. Go to **File → Project Structure** and the select '**Facets**'. Click on the **+** button and Add '**Android**'. In **Choose Module** pop up select your project and Click '**OK**' and then click '**Apply**'

[image]

You can now find **Profiler** tab in bottom menu and also from **View -> Tool Windows**

Answer (score 2):

The `Profile` option won't show up in tab until we build and run latest code of our branch. 
**Just run again** and `Profile` option would show up.